# sample Bash script or command to retrieve number files in directory

Tags: linux, shell

I have problem with number of files in directory

I use

```
$(ls /test -l | grep '^-' | wc -l)
```

but this way I retrieve just number of files in the same path but don't retrieve number of files in subdirectors
 if I have

```
  /test/1
  /test/1/2
  /test/1/3
  /test/1/4/1
  /test/1/4/2
  /test/1/5
```

my question is how to retrieve number of files in /test ?
Thanks for advice.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

try this

```
targetDir=/test
find ${targetDir} -type f | wc -l
```

I hope this helps.

Answer (score 2):

```
$(ls -lR /test | grep '^-' | wc -l)
```

Better to use find

```
$(find /test -type f | wc -l)
```

Answer (score 1):

the standard way is to use `find`

`find /test -type f | wc -l`

Other methods include using the shell (eg bash 4)

```
shopt -s globstar
shopt -s dotglob
declare -i count=0
for file in **
do
  if [ -f "$file" ];then
     ((count++))
  fi
done
echo "total files: $count"
```

Or a programming language, such as Perl/Python or Ruby

```
ruby -e 'a=Dir["**/*"].select{|x|File.file?(x)};puts a.size'
```

Comment: You don't need to build the array just to find its size: `count = Dir["**/*"].inject(0) {|c,x| File.file?(x) ? c+1 : c}; puts count`

Comment: @glenn, yep, i actually wanted to change that but thought to leave it status quo since he had already got an answer. However, my defense would be we can use the array for later, if desired :)

Answer (score 1):

Using `wc -l` is the easiest way, but if you want to count files **accurately** it's more complicated:

```
count_files()
{
    local file_count=0
    while IFS= read -r -d '' -u 9
    do
        let file_count=$file_count+1
    done 9< <( find "$@" -type f -print0 )
    printf %d $file_count
}
```

As a bonus you can use this to count in several directories at the same time.

To test it:

```
test_dir="$(mktemp -d)"
touch "${test_dir}/abc"
touch "${test_dir}/foo
bar
baz"
count_files "$test_dir"
```

Comment: Can you please explain why `wc -l` is inaccurate, when preceded by `find . -type f` ?